# fit_generator flags stop iteration issue and predicted image is empty

Tags: keras, unet-neural-network

I'm trying to run unet architecture for medical images for segmentation. I used code from https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet. The actual size of my image is 800x600 and I had resized the image to 800x400 for training in unet. while predicting I'm getting error as stop iteration when I try to test for 8 images. It runs successfully with 1 image but the predicted output image is empty. Some one help me to fix the issue.

code is taken from https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet
Modification done in data.py:

`def trainGenerator(batch_size,train_path,image_folder,mask_folder,aug_dict,image_color_mode = "grayscale",mask_color_mode = "grayscale",image_save_prefix  = "image",mask_save_prefix  = "mask",flag_multi_class = False,num_class = 2,save_to_dir = None,target_size = (400,800),seed = 1):`

`def testGenerator(test_path,num_image = 9,
target_size = (400,800),
flag_multi_class = False,as_gray = True):`

changed size of the image from(256,256) to (400,800)

modification done in model.py->

`def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (400,800,1)):`

[image: test image]

Comment: You always have to include full error messages in questions.

Comment: Error message:
Exception in thread Thread-40:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ksr-ece/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/ksr-ece/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ksr-ece/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 568, in data_generator_task
    generator_output = next(self._generator)
StopIteration